# Examples of competing genericized trademarks

Tags: trademarks

I suppose everyone is at least implicitly aware of the concept of a [genericized trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks). Are there any examples of *competing* genericized trademarks? Especially with respect to region. For example, if everyone in, say, Michigan, called facial tissues "Quilted Northerns" instead of "Kleenex."

Comment: You mean, are there known cases where one community uses "Kleenex" generically and another community uses "Northerns"?

Comment: Yeah, or similar. Like if 30% of Americans said "Bing it" instead of "Google it."

Comment: A quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks--only one caught my attention: AmE Scotch tape, BrE Sellotape.

Comment: @Xanne Excellent! Would you care to add that as an answer? Or I could add it and update with any others that I or anyone else thinks of.

Comment: @Evan You go ahead and do it.  I didn't do enough research to satisfy myself on why there aren't more regional or country differences or how, if there are, they develop.  It seems to me a little open-ended.

Comment: @Lawrence fixed. "Kleenex" was implied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases of this:

1. [Sellotape (UK et al.) and Scotch Tape (US & Canada)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks). From Xanne's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381332/examples-of-competing-genericized-trademarks?noredirect=1#comment898054_381332).

Comment: As it turns out, Sellotape and Scotch Tape are used as generics but are still under trademark protection, as are many product names being used generically.  These two are made by different companies.

Comment: @Xanne. True. I'm not concerned about whether the terms are currently or formerly trademarked.